# create RSS in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, rss

how can i create an Rss window for news in my form?

Comment: You question title and body ask different questions, you got one answer for each...

Comment: what the diffrence?
anyway, i want to creat an rss in my form in C#

Comment: No, these are two different question: create RSS means, how can i write an xml that behaves like an rss feed. And an rss window in my form would be how can i read an rss xml file and show the content in some formatted way?

Comment: -1: Way too many onliner questions being asked with little context and no code samples.  If you really want people to put some effort into helping you should put more effort in yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rss is just an xml file so it is very easy to create it. If you want to use some library to make the process easier you can use [RSS Toolkit.](http://aspnetrsstoolkit.codeplex.com/)

You can read rss specification at [RSS 2.0 Specification.](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are two libraries / frameworks that can help you.

- [**System.ServiceModel.Syndication**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.aspx)
- [**Argotic Syndication
  Framework**](http://argotic.codeplex.com/)

you can have look at following tutorial series for how can make use of them

- [**Really simple syndication,  An Introduction about RSS with
  .Net**](http://codingphobia.com/2009/07/03/really-simple-syndication-rss-with-net/)
- [**How to Generate Rss and Atom Feeds**](http://codingphobia.com/category/rss-feed/)

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This article from MSDN I found really helpful with creating an RSS feed.  Remember you don't have to do it this way, since RSS is really just an xml document.  You could do it many way.

[Creating an Online RSS News Aggregator with ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478968.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

using WCF or at least the System.Servicemodel.Syndication namespace, there is the SyndicationFeed and Rss20FeedFormatter that are very usefull for this

edit

[here](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/How-to-create-a-syndication-feed-for-your-website.aspx) is a good example, essentially the SyndicationFeed is a class that can be built up with SyndicationItems (which in turn have several properties to fill in), the Rss20FeedFormatter then formats that, in WCF you can return the Rss20FeedFromatter as though it is XML, I think the same is true if you use it in a asmx web servic etoo.

Comment: @aharont I added some more info for you

Comment: @aharont my response is based on the assumption you wanted a feed, after reading you question I am not sure that is what you want, you may ned to clarify a little